# Redirect htaccess /index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Добрый день, нужно сделать редирект с site-fite.com/index.php на  site-fite.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|uploads|js|tiny_mce|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|css|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ http://site-fite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\-fite\.com\.ua$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\-fite\.com\.ua$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/site\-fite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /ru/glavnaya http://site-fite.com/
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Я попробовал сделать, но у меня циклическая переадресация получилась.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

В этом блоке:

- проверка, что URI запроса не начинается с /index.php
- проверка, что файл запроса не существую
- проверка, что директория запроса не существует
- если хотя бы одна из проверок выполнена успешно, то:

  - выполнить редирект на /index.php
  - добавить строку запросу (флаг QSA, строка запроса - это параметры после знака вопроса)
  - считать это правило последним (не выполнять правила, которые следуют ниже)

С учетом этих правил, можно будет удалить текущие:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|uploads|js|tiny_mce|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|css|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ http://site-fite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\-fite\.com\.ua$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\-fite\.com\.ua$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/site\-fite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

А перед новым правилом редиректа на /index.php стоит добавить следующее:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|tiff|ico|ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,QSA,L]
```

Это правило для вывода ошибки 404 при запросе картинок, стилей, js и т.п. файлов, которые не стоит редиректить на /index.php

Comment: К сожалению не работает((

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1t9kvzte/
вот такой сейчас хтасес

Comment: И какой результат, как статус ответа?